# In Slack, we start a quoted paragraph with '>>>'. How do we end a quoted paragraph?

Tags: slack

In Slack, we start a quoted paragraph with **>>>**.

Is there a way to end the quoted paragraph, and continue writing more *unquoted* text in the *same* message?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no function to turn off quoting again after using `>>>`.

If you just want to quote some part of a text you want to use `>` which will create a quote until the next line break only. The output will still be automatically formatted on multiple lines if the needed.

See [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages) for reference.